# Retrieve deleted AWS S3 file by version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to retrieve a deleted file from s3, without restoring it. I can do it through the console (clicking Download), but I need to do it programmatically.

The following call lists the version I need:

```
s3.list_object_versions(
    Bucket="...", 
    KeyMarker="/.../part-00000-5ceb032b-c918-47df-a2ad-f02f3790077a-c000.csv", 
    VersionIdMarker = "A1GxocexjsirkzKfo47lvQ0r7ythwCWM",
    MaxKeys=1
)
```

However, s3.get_object() with the same parameters, returns *"ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchVersion) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified version does not exist."*

What is the proper way of retrieving a specific version of a deleted file?

Comment: How exactly do you use `get_object`?

Comment: ```contents = s3.get_object(
    Bucket="...", 
    Key="/.../part-00000-5ceb032b-c918-47df-a2ad-f02f3790077a-c000.csv", 
    VersionId = "A1GxocexjsirkzKfo47lvQ0r7ythwCWM")["Body"].read()```

Comment: What is that `/.../`? Your actual prefix?

Comment: Yes, I blanked out some portions of it, I don't want posted.

Comment: I mean, prefixies do not start with `/`. So is it what you actually have in your code?

Comment: You are quite right. If I remove the leading / it works!

Comment: Ok. I will make answer then, if you do not mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments. The issue was caused by using  `/` in a key a prefix. [Prefixes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html) **do not start** with a `/`. Thus it should be:

```
KeyMarker=".../part-00000-5ceb032b-c918-47df-a2ad-f02f3790077a-c000.csv"
```